# java KeyListener not Working regularly

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm tried to develop a 2 rackets game. I create 2 rectangles (as rackets).
I try to control them from the keyboard and use **KeyListener** Event Handler for this purpose... When I run my program sometime it works and sometimes not.
I'm wondering why it works one time but no other.
Here is my code.
Kindly let me know where I'm making mistake?
Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

JFrame f;
MyPanel p; // Instance of MyPanel for left and right rackets
BallPanel bp; // Instance of BallPanel for Bouisng ball
int x1, y1, x2, y2;
int x, y;

public Test(){
    f = new JFrame("2 Rackets Game");

    Container c = f.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    x = 5; y = 10;

    p = new MyPanel();
    bp = new BallPanel();

    c.add(bp);
    c.add(p);

    f.setSize(600, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p.addKeyListener(this);
    p.setFocusable(true);

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    t.start();
    }


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/*_______*/}
    int speed = 30;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        p.mY1 -= speed;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        p.mY1 += speed;
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            p.mY2 -= speed;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p.mY2 += speed;
    }
   p.repaint();
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {/*_______*/}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (f.getWidth()-25 == bp.mX){
        x = -5;
    }
    if (f.getHeight()-50 == bp.mY){
        y = -2;
    }
    if(bp.mX == 0){
        x = 5;
    }
    if(bp.mY == 0){
        y = 2;
    }
    bp.mX += x;
    bp.mY += y;

    bp.repaint();
}

 public static void main(String arg[]){
    Test t = new Test();
}
```

}
[Screenshot of Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQjoc.png)

Alos here is code for "MyPanel" class (Used to paint rectangles on screen)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
// variables used to draw rectangles at different locations
int mX1  = 20;
int mY1 = 120;

int mX2 = 560;
int mY2 = 120;
// overriding paintComponent method
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    // Left Racket
    g2.fillRect(mX1, mY1, 5, 80);
    //Right Racket
    g2.fillRect(mX2, mY2, 5, 80);
}
```

}

Comment: As with all issues related to `KeyListener` - use the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, problem solved

Comment: I'm new to java programming... please explain briefly..

Comment: Read the tutorial, read the duplicate question, there are copious numbers of examples